# How can I avoid a memory leak in my .net Application (using VLC)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-leaks

Im building a digital signage application. I need to show a mix of images and videos (3 images and then a video - then repeat this). I am using a WPF application for this. I ran out of luck using the "MediaElement" in WPF - I had some files that would not play (even the default "wildlife.wmv" file in some situations). I turned to VLC and now my application only runs for ~3 hours before i run out of memory / my vlc player going black.

I have a VLC component wrapped inside a Windows Forms component. The Windows Forms component is then added to my WPF application.

My code is shown below. Im loading this using reflection - I found this using the least amount of memory. Been going about with this for hours.

```
//code
 string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
 string directory = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Directory.FullName;
 string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "MedianVLCLibrary.dll");
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(newPath))
 {
   Assembly vlcAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(newPath);
   myVlcType = vlcAssembly.GetType("MedianVLCLibrary.VLCUserControl");
 }
 else
 {
   MedianLog.Log.Instance.LogFatal("Could not fild MedianVLCLibrary.dll");
   throw new FileNotFoundException(newPath);
 }
 obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myVlcType);
 this.presentationGrid.Children.Add((UIElement)obj); //adding the ui element to the WPF grid
 MethodInfo playMethod = myVlcType.GetMethod("Play");
 playMethod.Invoke(obj, new object[] { file });
 EventInfo completedEvent = myVlcType.GetEvent("PlayCompleted");
 Delegate completedDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(completedEvent.EventHandlerType, this, "PlayerCompleted");
```

completedEvent.AddEventHandler(obj, completedDelegate);

And then im doing my cleanup in my "PlayComplete" method before im invoking a callback method.

```
obj = null;
myVlcType = null;
vlcAssembly = null;
this.presentationGrid.Children.Clear();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
FinishedCallback();
```

I have made a wrapper around VLC, using samples found online. Please see code below.

```
 public partial class VLCUserControl : UserControl, IDisposable
    {
        AxVLCPlugin2 vlc;
        public VLCUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vlc = new AxVLCPlugin2();
            vlc.BeginInit();
            windowsFormsHost.Child = vlc;
            vlc.EndInit();
        }

        public void Play(string path)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(path);
            var convertedURI = uri.AbsoluteUri;
            vlc.playlist.add(convertedURI, null, null);
            vlc.playlist.play();
            vlc.MediaPlayerEndReached += Vlc_MediaPlayerEndReached;
        }

        private void Vlc_MediaPlayerEndReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            vlc.playlist.items.clear();
            vlc.MediaPlayerEndReached -= Vlc_MediaPlayerEndReached;
            if (PlayCompleted != null)
            {
                PlayCompleted();
            }           
            //vlc = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            vlc.Dispose();
        }

        public event Action PlayCompleted;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using reflection to do this. I can't believe the VLC library recommends being used in this way... I'd assume that the VLC component implements `IDisposable` which would dispose of the resources and that you aren't doing this - and if you create a new VLC instance each time then that's going to probably be where your memory leak comes from.

Comment: Why are you loading the vlc assembly at runtime? Can you not add a reference to it? Also, if you are using event handlers, it is possible to that things are not GCd because they are being referenced when it subscribed to some event.

Comment: @chris - I made a wrapper for the VLC control (see code above). That was the only way i could get it into my WPF control. I new it up every time i need it, you suggest i hold a newed up version in a reference and then add it only when needed and then gives it a new path to play every time?